# Map<String,Object> type is not applicable for the arguments Map<String,String[]>

Tags: java, generics

Why am i getting this error

```
public void getParameters(Map<String,Object> param){

}

public void test(){

    Map<String,String[]> testMap = new HashMap<String,String[]>();

    getParameters(testMap);  // type is not applicable error here

}
```

since i can pass String array to object like below. Can someone explain this please ?

```
public void getParameters(Object param){

}

public void test(){

    String[] testArray = new String[10];

    getParameters(testArray);

}
```

Comment: This is perfectly normal.  You'd need to change your `getParameters` method to accept `Map<String, ?>`.

Comment: `String[]` _is-a_ `Object`, but `Map<String,String[]>` _is-NOT-a_ `Map<String,Object>`. Inheritance doesn't work that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

String extends Object so that works but generics does not work that way.

Good explanation here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/subtype.html

Answer (score 4):

Java uses copy by values which means you can safely do this

```
String s = "Hello";
Object o = s;
o = 5; // `s` is not corrupted by this.
```

However you can't change something which references a different type.

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("hi", "hello");
Map<String, Object> map2 = (Map) map;
map2.put("hi", 5); // map now has an Integer value in it.

String s = map.get("hi"); // ClassCastException.
```

This is why you cannot safely pass an `Map<String, String[]>` as an `Map<String, Object[]>` because the latter would let you do

```
Object[] os = new Integer[1];
param.put("hi", os); // Your Map<String, String[]> is corrupted.
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a exact match of the type parameters of the relevant class. This means `Map<String, String[]>` is not assignable to `Map<String, Object>`. To make your code work use a wildcard:

```
public void getParameters(Map<String, ? extends Object> param){

}
```

or in this case simply

```
public void getParameters(Map<String, ?> param){

}
```